# HTML not valid when no rows are generated by a SQL query

Tags: php, html, validation

Here is my code:

```
echo '<table class="class1"><tbody>';
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
 echo '<tr><td>'.$row1['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row1['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

When I use the HTML validator, it returns a good and a proper error "trimming empty `<tbody>`". It happens in the case when there are 0 rows selected. So, the code looks like `<table><tbody></tbody></table>`, and that is not good.

I'm thinking of the best way to exclude this error (do not display this table at all when there are 0 rows or something like that), but I don't know the best way how to do that.

How's the idea to check `if mysql_num_rows()>0` before choosing to display `echo '<table class="class1"><tbody>';` ? Any better ideas or is this one good?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()>0` or `mysql_num_rows()` alone is fine

Comment: Why do you need a `<tbody>` tag?
Whatever, check `mysql_num_rows` (as you proposed), or collect data from query to another array and if its not empty display it.

Offtopic: are you from Grodno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows($result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check whether the query has any results. If true, create a table + rows. Otherwise, do nothing, or add an alternative block:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<table class="class1"><tbody>';
    while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
       echo '<tr><td>'.$row1['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row1['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
} else { //Optional
    echo '<!-- Anything -->';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is absolutely fine. Don't forget to include the closing `echo '</tbody></table>';`
 in your `if` check as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is best practise or not, but this should work:

```
$string = "";
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
  $string .= '<tr><td>'.$row1['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row1['lastname'].'</td></tr>';
}
if ($string!="") {
  echo '<table class="class1"><tbody>';
  echo $string;
  echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Comment: With a large set of records, nothing will be shown until the loop has finished.

Comment: Psst. You can insert code(without it being parsed), by prefixing each line by four spaces.